# R: PDA on 2 manners but with different results?

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm working on a project where I have to classify data about breast cancer. I want to use PDA. I'm trying to found the optimal value for lambda by 10-fold cross validation. 
I've started with:

```
breast[,1] <- as.numeric(breast[,1])   #Because this code only works when the classes are numeric (so not factors like they were)
```

I found that this could be done by:

```
library(penalizedLDA)
PenalizedLDA.cv(breast[,-1], breast[,1], lambdas = seq(0,0.5,by=.01), nfold = 10)
```

But I can also do this manually:

```
lam <- seq(0,1,by=.01)
length(lam)
error.lam <- rep(0, length(lammie))
for (la in 1:101){
  error.pda <- rep(0,10)
  for (fold in 1:k){  
   currentFold <- folds[fold][[1]]
   breast.pda = fda(Diagnosis~., data=breast[-currentFold,], method=gen.ridge, lambda = lam[la])
   pred.pda = predict(breast.pda, newdata= breast[currentFold,-1], type="class")
   CV.table=table(breast[currentFold,1],pred.pda)
   error.pda[fold] <- CV.table[1,2]+CV.table[2,1] 
  }
  error.lam[la] <- sum(error.pda)/nrow
}
```

The strange thing now is that I become two different results. For the first I've got a CV-error of 4.4% and value for lambda 0.055. While for the second one I become CV-error 6.32% and lamba 0.55. Could someone explain me the differences between those two methods?

Silke

Comment: This has happened to me several times and the reason is always the same: human error. There is probably some detail present in `PenalizedLDA.cv` that is missing your implementation. Never reimplement other people's code if it gets the job done (although it can be very tempting sometimes), or you'll waste time and risk committing mistakes.

Comment: What I mean is, it is probably irrelevant why the implementations don't agree since you will most likely find out that the official is better than yours. Do you use the same folds btw?

Comment: Hello!No I don't use the same folds because in the first method they select automatically their folds. But I think I can avoid this by the next option:

Comment: folds: Optional - one can pass in a list containing the observations that should be used
as the test set in each cross-validation fold.

Comment: Now I've used the same folds and still 2 procent change between the 2 methods.

Comment: That's odd. The code looks fine to me so I guess you need to go bug hunting then. I'm afraid that's not really the type of problems SO is indented for though, since the solution is unlikely to be of interest to anybody but you. But the best of luck to you!